# With nested named groups in a regex, possible to navigate hierarchy?

Tags: .net, regex

I've developed a regex that matches [pstops](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pstops.htm) page specifications. (Regex whitespace not significant.)

```
^(?:(?<modulo>\d+):)?
(?<pages>
  (?<pagespec>
    (?<pageno>-?\d+)
    (?<rotation>[RUL]?)?
    (?:@(?<scale>\d*(?:\.\d+)))?
    (?:\(
      (?<xoff>\d*\.?\d+)(?<xunit>in|cm|w|h)?
      ,
      (?<yoff>\d*\.?\d+)(?<yunit>in|cm|w|h)?
    \))?
  \+?)+,?
)+$
```

.

```
'Sample string:
'"4:1L@.7(21cm,0)+-2L@.7(21cm,14.85cm),1L(21cm,0)+-2L@.7(21cm,14.85cm)"
```

As you can see, there are nested named subgroups. A `pagespec` need not specify `rotation`, for example. I would like to be able to do something to the effect of this:

```
If match.Groups("pages").Captures(0).Groups("pagespecs").Captures(1).Groups("rotation").Value > ""
```

but of course `Captures` has no `Groups` property. Is there any way to access subgroups in the hierarchy in this way?

EDIT: Here is a more minmal example (white space significant this time):

```
(?<paragraph>(?:(?<sentence>The (?<child>boy|girl) is hungry\.|The (?<parent>mother|father) is angry\.)\s*)+)
```

Matched against this string:

```
The boy is hungry. The mother is angry. The girl is hungry.
```

produces one match. Within that match,

- `Groups("paragraph")` has one capture matching the entire string.
- `Groups("sentence")` has three captures.
- `Groups("child")` has two captures, `boy` and `girl`.
- `Groups("parent")` has one capture, `mother`.

But there is nothing that tells me that the single capture for `parent` lies within the second capture for `sentence`, unless I start looking at `Index` and `Length` for each capture.

EDIT: Here's the final answer:

```
^(?:(?<modulo>\d+):)?
(?<pages>
  (?<pagespec>
    (?<pageno>-?\d+)
    (?<rotation>[RUL]?)
    (?:@(?<scale>\d*(?:\.\d+)))?
    (?:\(
      (?<xoff>\d*\.?\d+)(?<xunit>in|cm|w|h)?
      ,
      (?<yoff>\d*\.?\d+)(?<yunit>in|cm|w|h)?
    \))?
    (?<pageno>)(?<rotation>)(?<scale>)(?<xoff>)(?<xunit>)(?<yoff>)(?<yunit>)
  \+?)+,?
 (?<pagespec>)
)+
```

This pushes a `NULL` onto the `pagespec` stack between each `page`, so they can be correlated with `page`; and a `NULL` onto each of the other named stacks between each `pagespec`.  Gee, parsing is hard ...

Comment: I guess it would help for the usefulness of the question if you reduced this to a minimal example. Something like matching `x-y@z` with `(?:(?<part>(?:(?<sub>[a-z])|-)+|@)+` would probably do (as in, how do I know if `Groups("sub").Captures(1)` belongs to `Groups("part").Captures(0)` or `(1)`). But great question, I'd be interested in a solution, too :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. As far as I know, different groups have no relation to each other with regard to how they are nested in the pattern. Moreover, such a hierarchy wouldn't even make sense, because group names can be reused in .NET:

```
(?<group>
  (?<sub>.)
)+
(?<sub>.)
```

I guess it would be somehow possible to represent this a hierarchical tree as well, but this would defeat the purpose of the stacks, .NET maintains for captures. Maybe I should clarify that: .NET does not simply list all the captures of a group - it pushes them onto a stack from which they can be popped again with `(?<-sub>)` for instance. Now how would you treat that, if an instance of a group later on pops something from the stack that was matched way earlier? I think it would become highly unintuitive if not impossible to solve for the general case.

What you actually want is to group your `pagespecs` captures by how they correspond to a single "instance" of `pages`. You can do this by the very reason that prevents the solution, you'd like to have: you can reuse groups:

```
^(?:(?<modulo>\d+):)?
(?<pages>
  (?<pagespecs>
     # here goes your actual pagespec pattern
  [+]?)+
  (?<pagespecs>)
  ,?
)+$
```

Now at the end of every `page` you push an empty string on to the `pagespecs` stack. Since a normal "instance" of `pagespecs` will always contain at least one character, you know that any empty captures must have come from that separate use of `pagespecs`. So you can now split you `Captures("pagespecs")` by the empty-string elements, and then just associate them sequentially with the elements in `Captures("pages")`.

Comment: Note that a pagespec doesn't have to have a rotation. I might have one page, five pagespecs and only one rotation. How do I associate that one rotation with the correct pagespec?

Comment: OK, rotation was a bad example - it seems that it turns up as NULL when not present.  But xoff/xunit/yoff/yunit are in an unnamed capture group which is totally optional.  Omitting that destroys the association.

Comment: Ah, I get it now! I need to add a NULL-pushing group FOR EACH NAMED SUBGROUP. Then I can correlate properly!  Thank you!!

Comment: @RossPresser haha, glad you figured it out while I was gone :D